# openshift metrics deployer error

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

Metrics-deployer pod is not running.error logs of the pod is:

```
openshift admin ca create-signer-cert --key=/etc/deploy/_output/ca.key --cert=/etc/deploy/_output/ca.crt --serial=/etc/deploy/_output/ca.serial.txt --name=metrics-signer@1527434760
```

Error: unknown command "admin" for "openshift"

Comment: I guess the problem is with the admin command.Try using the help command to check if the order of where the admin command needs to be changed or if there is an alternate to that command.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try: oc adm ca create-signer-cert --key=/etc/deploy/_output/ca.key --cert=/etc/deploy/_output/ca.crt --serial=/etc/deploy/_output/ca.serial.txt --name=metrics-signer@1527434760